# Config maps not getting deleted when deleting flink session cluster

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam-io

I am deploying flink session cluster (Version: 1.14.0) with HA in kubernetes
I install the cluster using helm.
When the helm is uninstalled the JM and TM are deleted but config-maps are not getting deleted.

```
NAME                                                                         DATA   AGE
wcm-aggregation-cluster-dispatcher-leader                                    2      2d5h
wcm-aggregation-cluster-resourcemanager-leader                               2      2d5h
wcm-aggregation-cluster-restserver-leader                                    2      2d5h
```

I am not sure why this is not getting deleted by flink

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/ha/kubernetes_ha/#high-availability-data-clean-up):

"HA related ConfigMaps will be retained because they do not set the owner reference. When restarting the cluster, all previously running jobs will be recovered and restarted from the latest successful checkpoint."

These configmaps contains details about the HA services, if they were deleted everytime there is a helm uninstall, HA data would be lost and you would probably have to restore from a savepoint or start from scratch.